# Is there any Eclipse plug-in to generate sequence diagram from ja va code

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Is there any Eclipse plug-in to generate sequence diagram from java code? i tried searching in market place, did not find a good open source plug-in.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but be sure to [provide enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that [Papyrus](https://eclipse.org/papyrus/) would suffice.